# How to improve flexbox performance under Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, flexbox

Are there some guidelines to improve flexbox rendering performance under Firefox ?

I'm developing a one page app using Angular2 and I heavily rely on flexboxes to define the layout. Certain element in the layout are resizeable by the user. (Like the different panel in a jsfiddle)

Using chrome the performance are really snappy and there aren't any problem.
But when I use Firefox and I try to resize some elements, everything lags like hell and the app isn't usable anymore.

You can see the effects on this page :

https://cpa-level-it.github.io/flexbox/

There is a slider between the main content block and second content block.
If you move the slider with Chrome it'll be very smooth. With Firefox it'll start lagging.

The problem seems to come from the flexbox used in each pane of the slider.
The (simplified) slider html is :

```
 <vertical-split-pane>
     <div class="left-component">
         <div class="split-pane-content-primary>
             ...Main Content...
         </div> 
     </div>
     <div class="separator"></div>
     <div class="right-compontent">
         <div class="split-pane-content-secondary>
             ...Second Content...
         </div> 
     </div>
 </vertical-split-pane>
```

And here is the css that create the flexbox :

```
vertical-split-pane {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-component,
.right-component { 
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.split-pane-content-primary,
.split-pane-content-secondary {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If I disable the `display: flex` on `.left-component, .right-component` then it's smooth on Firefox too. But I need those flexboxes to limit the height for my scrolling list in the main content.

The full source code is available at : https://github.com/cpa-level-it/flexbox

Thanks

Comment: It is required for you to post your code here, a minimal example that shows the problem, not a third party site that may change or disappear tomorrow helping no one.

Comment: I'm using chrome on a mac and it's slow as well.  Usually javascript is slower than css.  I would look into the javascript.

Comment: The note on your link states you are using Firefox versions less than 38 which is an unsupported version that is two years old compared to the current version of Chrome. The current Firefox version is 51. I don't see the issue you are talking about in Firefox.

Comment: I'm using version 45 and still have issues comparing to chrome. I'll try to make a more complete example tomorrow.

Comment: @Rob I just updated my question with a more complete example (that should have the same issue on Firefox 51)

Comment: For me it looks like there is used `setTimeout` for `vertical-split-separator` element when moving it.

Comment: What is this: `<vertical-split-pane>`? That isn't valid HTML.

Comment: `<vertical-split-pane>` is a custom angular2 directive from the ng2-split-pane package. The problem there is when this directive contains flexboxes the performances under Firefox aren't good. With Chrome there is no problem.

@Justinas : It doesn't seem to use `setTimeout`. `mouse-down` event is used when we click on the slider to start dragging then `mouse-move` event is used to update each pane width with `pane.style.width = xx%`.

Comment: Ok it seems that for now Firefox has some performances problems with flexboxes. A patch is in the work : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209697